# File Explorer Can See Folder But Can't See File Windows 10 Network Sharing

Tags: windows, es-file-explorer

I can't seem to see the files in the folders from my shared folder. I turned all of the password and everything off for ease. But it doesn't seem to work. I can see the folders and everything. But not the files. Just folders.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site for more than 5 years, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Most apps that can access SMB/CIFS shares only support SMBv1 which is deprecated and disabled on new Windows systems. Windows 10 by default only suports SMBv2 and SMBv3.

SMBv1 is mainly disabled because of security problems that simplify an infection of your computer e.g. by a worm.

From what I have read ES-FileExplorer currently only supports SMBv1. Therefore I assume this may be the cause for the problem you have observed.

The number of apps that support at least SMBv2 is currently not very long. The following apps seem to support SMBv2 or at least claim to do so:

- [Solid Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer2)
- [AndSMB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lysesoft.andsmb)
- [FX File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.fx)
- [X-plore File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lonelycatgames.Xplore)

Comment: Did this just happen after the April update on any recent update? It was working fine a couple of week ago.

Comment: If I understand it right new installations since Windows 10 1709 no longer include SMBv1. If this also applies tu upgrades is unknown to me: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4034314/smbv1-is-not-installed-by-default-in-windows

Comment: @Robert re: Windows 10 - SMBv1, perhaps [this answer on another question](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/193602/44325) may be relevant?